# High CPU usage issue because of cron jobs

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, cron, multiprocessing, anomaly-detection

**I apologize for the long question but I have to explain it.**

I am doing a **change point detection** through python for almost 50 customers and for different processes.

- I am getting minute by minute interval numeric data from influx.
- I am calculating the Z-Score and saving that in mongoDB locally on
  the
     machine on which the cron job is running.
- I am comparing the Z-score with historic Z-score and then I am
  alerting 
     the system.

### Issues:

1. As i am doing this for 50 customers which can scale to say 500 or
   5000 and each customer will
       be having say 10 process so its not practical to have that many cron jobs.
2. Increasing cron jobs are creating high cpu usage and as my data is
   sitting locally and if I 
       will loose the linux machine then i will loose all my data sitting there and won't be able to
       compare it with historic data.

### Solutions:

1. Create a clustered mongoDB server rather than having the data saved 
   locally.
2. Replace the cron jobs with multi threading and multi processing.

### Suggestions:

1. **What could be the best way to implement this to decrease the load on 
       cpu considering this is going to run all the time in a loop?**
2. **After fixing the above, what could be the best way to decrease the 
       false positive numbers in alerts?**

#### Keep in mind:

- Its a time series data.
- Every time stamp has 5 or 6 variables and as of now i am doing the
  same 
     operation for each variable separately.

> ```
> Time        var1      var2     var3.................varN
>
> 09:00 PM    10,000    5,000    150,000..............10
>
> 09:01 PM    10,500    5,050    160,000..............25
> ```

There is possibility that there is a correlation in these numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Amiram thanks for the edit but any suggestions do you have?